# How to string match elements in arrays to index in another dataframe and perform operations?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series which contains arrays and it looks like:

```
[array(['Person A', 34.0], dtype=object),
 array(['Person C', 30.0], dtype=object)]
```

I have another dataframe which contains information on all persons in the database which looks like:

```
Index     Score_week41 Score_week42  Score_week43  Score_week44  Score_week45
Person A  6            2             3             4             7
Person B  0            3             4             2             1
Person C  1            2             4             0             8
```

How can I match the persons in the arrays to the persons in the dataframe? I also would like to be able to specify a range such as 'Score_week42':'Score_week44', in which the average score for the matched person in the specified range shows up.

So for example, the output can look like:

```
[array(['Person A', 34.0, 3], dtype=object),
 array(['Person C', 30.0, 2], dtype=object)]
```

where '3' and '2' are the average scores between the range week 42 and week 44 for Person A and Person C respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more convenient to store these series statistics in dataframe in case you want to expand with new columns

```py
# your dataframe
all_data = pd.read_csv("people.csv", index_col="Index") 

# your previous series
people_stat = pd.DataFrame([np.array(['Person_A', 34.0], dtype=object), np.array(['Person_C', 30.0], dtype=object)], columns=["People", "Number"]).set_index("People") 

people_stat["mean"] = all_data.loc[people_stat.index, "Score_week42":"Score_week44"].mean(1)
print(people_stat)
```

outputs:

```
          Number  mean
People                
Person_A    34.0   3.0
Person_C    30.0   2.0
```

people.csv

```
Index,Score_week41,Score_week42,Score_week43,Score_week44,Score_week45
Person_A,6,2,3,4,7
Person_B,0,3,4,2,1
Person_C,1,2,4,0,8
```